# Windows Phone null reference

Tags: windows-phone

My project was working fine, then I decided to upload it to the store and there were a few things I changed on the app; these changes were the display name and the language of this app.

My project deployed perfectly, then by a reason I don´t know it told me `PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled` was `null`, some other times it tells me the first element right after the Initialize Component says it´s null.

I really don't know what's happening, but I really want to upload the app on the store.

Comment: A little hard to understand your problem. Do you get the problem in Visual Studio, or when you run the app after publish to the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exception usually happens when you change either Assembly Name or Namespace in Project Properties.
To fix, just delete Bin and Obj folders and rebuild.
Hope this will help.